# Python input validation no if-else or isdigit or try

Tags: python, validation, input

Had an exam and couldn’t figure this out. We can only use what we learnt.

So Input validation without using if elif or if-else statements 
Check if input is a number.
We haven’t covered try 
Or isdigit.
Any other way?

Comment: try parsing it as a number and see if you get an error - `int(value)`

Comment: What have you learned?

Comment: Use `try-except`.

Comment: @blhsing one of the few things they said is no `try`...

Comment: @SpghttCd - You only need the `try/except` if you want to graciously handle an invalid input..

Comment: Welcome to SO Please understand that most of the People here don't want to - well, _use_ their time to guess what you might mean. So please: [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @Sayse I don't get your point, sorry. IMO your program simply stops by throwing an error when not handled by try/except if e.g. `int('asdf')` had to be processed.

Comment: Given the vague explanation given, it would be a valid approach i.e you're writing a class library and want to leave the error handling to the implementor. I'm guessing the exam was looking for a for loop to check if each character is in a string of 0-9 (they explicitly mention `isdigit` which would lead me to believe this would be a solution if allowed so positive integers only) but thats no fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that input chars is subset of digit chars

```
set(input()) <= set(map(str, range(10)))
```

Comment: And decimal numbers?

Comment: exactly as isdigit()

Comment: That's right, yes. Then perhaps it might do for them. If only they'd be a little more precise...

Answer (score 0):

Due to lack of information in question, assuming you have some idea of ascii.
This is a naive solution, but that's all i can assume you know.
You can get ASCII value of each character using the `ord()` function in python.

What you can do is, read the input as string, and iterate over each character and check if it is in the valid ascii range of 0-9. if the condition fails even for one char, return false. Again, this is definitely not the best solution possible. 
Code:

```
string = input()
for i in a:
     if ord(i) not in range(48,58):
             print('Not a number')
             break
 else:
     print('Is a number')
```

Also, this can be done with two lines only, but writing fully may help you to get the logic part more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Another little but incomplete approach:

```
def check(x):
    if x[0] =='-':
        s = set(x[1:])
        return s.issubset('0123456789.')
    else:
        s = set(x)
        return s.issubset('0123456789.')

x = input('? ')
while not check(x):
    x = input('? ')
print(float(x)**2)
```

Works with neg or pos integers or decimals.
Doesn't with scientific notation and crashes with nonsense using only valid chars like `1.2.3.4.5`...